# I want to make a curve with CSS3

Tags: css

I am trying to make a curve with the help of css.
I am new in this field so please help me.
Here is the source I have tried.

```
.box
{
    left: -10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 25%;
    transform: skewX(25deg);
}
```

Comment: Well, in css3 compliant browsers, that will work. What is the problem you're running into?

Comment: Do you mean a [curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve) or [slanted text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italic_type) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This...

```
.circle{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 100px;
border: 3px solid black;
background-color: green;
 }
or


   div
{
-ms-transform: skew(30deg,20deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: skew(30deg,20deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: skew(30deg,20deg);
}
```